# Submitting two HTML forms at once, one in current window and one in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to submit two HTML forms at the same time.  The issue I'm currently hitting is that calling the submissions in succession always causes the first submission to get aborted by the browser.  Since one of these submissions is being done inside a new browser window, there should be no conflict between them.  Is there a way to properly handle this scenario?  I do have jQuery available.

Comment: As mentioned below by Tachyon, it would probably be best to make an ajax call for the current page submit, and on its success, submit the form to a new window. This way if there is an error in either one you can display it on the initial page.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options (I'm assuming you are willing to make Ajax calls):

1. Merge the contents into 1 object and submit the object by making an Ajax call
2. Alternatively, wait for the first Ajax call to hit the callback, then make the second call

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  If I switch to making ajax calls, is there a way to make the page refresh as is done with a standard form submission?  I still need that behavior.

Comment: @user964210 After your second form submits successfully, you can call `window.location.reload()` to refresh the current page. If your form submitting to a new window is a POST, this will prompt the user to re-submit form data. In this case you will need to use a GET instead of POST, or check out Post/Redirect/Get - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @Tricky12 Thanks for the detailed comment. I would've had just said "use `window.location.reload()`".